# how to add code tag in rich text editor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have rich text editor, in that i want to add code button , on click code button i want HTML code tag, like bold, italic on click it will generating html tag like wise i want to generate code button also  `text here`

Here I'm adding only button ,i want function to generate html code `tag`

```
document.writeln('<td><img class="rteImage" src="' + imagesPath + 'code.gif" width="25" height="24" alt="Code" title="Code" onClick="rteCommand(\'' + rte + '\', \'code\', \'\')"></td>');
```

I know it's possible from java script , but i don't know how to do it?

Please help me...

Comment: What rich text editor?  Is it `contenteditable` or a plugin?  Please provide a complete example, that we can test.  Otherwise, you'll get a lot of solutions that fit the question, but not the problem.

Comment: the function only generate the html code tag on click button

Comment: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex16/richtexteditor/ please check this link...like i have one rich text editor...in that i want to add code tag....